# How to validate uniqueness of field based on another table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to validate `roll_no` field in `students` model based on `student_section` model field `section`,

student_section.rb

```
class StudentSection < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :standard_id, :presence=> {:message=>" cannot be blank"}

  validates :section_id, :presence=> {:message=>" cannot be blank"}

  validates :student_id, :presence=> {:message=>" cannot be blank"}
end
```

I add validation in student.rb as

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :student_id, :presence=> true
  validates :student_name, :presence=> true

  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i

  validates :phone, :length=>{:in => 8..15}

  validates :admission_no, :uniqueness=> { scope: :org_id} 

  validates :roll_no, :uniqueness=> { scope: @student_section.section_id}
end
```

but it throws unknown field section_id

Comment: Did this  `validates_uniqueness_of :roll_no, scope: :section_id` work?

Comment: Whats the relationship between `Student` and `StudentSection`?

Comment: It throws Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'students.section_id' @Pavan

Comment: make sure you have section_id column in your students table

Comment: Please post your models.

Comment: You should have `section_id` field in students table

Comment: Is possible to validate without section_id in student table @Pavan

Comment: May be by a virtual attribute. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make a relationship between `Student` and `StudentSection`. If I understand you correctly, you may create a `one-to-many` relation.
After that your validation should work fine.
However, if you will search for more complex validation logic - you may use `validates_with` statement ([validates_with at apidock.com](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_with))